# Defining resourceUrl of another portlet's controller in current portlet's JSP

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

I have two portlets with some set of controllers defined. We are using Spring MVC. In the View i.e JSP we defining some resourceUrls like

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="ListResourceUrl" id="getList"  ></portlet:resourceURL>
```

this refers to the controller which I have defined as

```
@ResourceMapping("getList")
    @ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getList(ResourceRequest request,ResourceResponse response) throws IOException {

.........
}
```

Now I want to define another resourceUrl referring to a controller which is defined in another portlet. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `liferay-portlet-ext.tld` instead of `liferay-portlet.tld`.

Here is almost the same number of tags, but you can add some extra-parameter.

> liferay-portlet:resourceURL is similar to portlet:resourceURL except it has
>   the additional attributes plid, portletName, anchor, and encrypt.

So you may use something like the following:

```
<%@taglib prefix="liferay-portlet" uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" %>

<liferay-portlet:resourceURL id="getList" var="ListResourceUrl" 
                             portletName="portletname_WAR_portletname" />
```

Where `portletname_WAR_portletname` is actual name of portlet, which is quite Liferay-specific.

Comment: @veeru-a-s does this work for you? If it is right answer, please consider to accept it, otherwise please provide your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this! The only thing I had to add was `<add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>` in the corresponding section in `liferay-portlet.xml` for the target portlet -- from [liferaysolution.com](http://www.liferaysolution.com/2013/06/reject-actionserveresource-url.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a PortletURL programmatically in a controller use PortletURLFactoryUtil. The following snippet should give you an idea:

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);
String portletId = "...";
Layout page = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayoutByFriendlyUrl(group, "...");
PortletURL portletURL = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(
        httpRequest, portletId, page.getPlid(), PortletRequest.RESOURCE_PHASE);
```