# Calling controller of one portlet from another portlet

Tags: java, controller, liferay, portlet

I have two portlets say portlet1 and portlet2. I have a controller defined portlet1 as

```
@ResourceMapping("getForm")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getForm(ResourceRequest request,ResourceResponse response) {
.....
}
```

Now I want to call this controller from portlet2. is there any way that I can achieve this? Let me tell you that both the portlets are not on the same page.

Comment: can't you try some form of inheritance ?

Comment: You already [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15155156/655756) similar questions and I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15155695/655756), how you may do this